# How to get customer identifier on Garden FI?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I have passed "https://api.banno.com/consumer/claim/customer_identifier" and phone number and email claims to fetch tokens. I got back the id_token with phone number and email, but that does not contain "https://api.banno.com/consumer/claim/customer_identifier". Is there any setting on the garden FI or on the test user that will prevent me from fetching the CIF?

Answer (score 1):

The `https://api.banno.com/consumer/claim/customer_identifier` claim is a *Restricted Claim* as noted in the [Authentication Framework / Overview / OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/openidconnectoauth/) page.

This means that developers can *request* the claim in the auth flow, but no data will be returned for that claim unless the administrator at the financial institution configures your External Application to allow that specific claim. (See [Consumer API/ Overview / Configuration](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/overview/configuration/) or [Plugin Framework Architecture / External Applications](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/externalapplications/) for details on how a financial institution can configure an External Application for their institution.)

In the special case of the *Garden* demo institution, Jack Henry is acting as if it is the 'institution' so we can configure your External Application to allow that claim if you provide us with your `Client ID` (which isn't a secret).

- (Keep the actual `Client Secret` a *secret* though, and don't share that with anyone.)